# Smallest possible perturbation that decreases the rank of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-rank, nuclear-norm

Suppose I have some positive semidefinite matrix $A$ with rank $r$. I would like to write down a positive semidefnite matrix $B$ of rank $(r-1)$ such that $|A - B|_1$ is minimal where $|X|_1 = Tr[(X^\star X)^{1/2}]$ and $X^
\star$ is the tranpose conjugate of $X$.

Obviously, one way to achieve this is to diagonalize $A$ and then simply replace its smallest eigenvalue, $\lambda_{\min}$, with zero. Call this matrix $B$. This reduces the rank by 1 and $|A - B|_1 = \lambda_{\min}$.

Is it possible to show that this is $B$ is indeed the optimal matrix that decreases the rank while minimizing $|A - B|_1$? In particular, this shows that $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenbasis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Keep in mind that you should not replace the *minimum* eigenvalue but rather the one which is smallest in absolute value. That this is the best rank $r-1$ approximation to your matrix $A$ can be proved by using the singular value decomposition of $A$. See the section on low-rank matrix approximation using the SVD on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Low-rank_matrix_approximation).

Comment: More generally, one should not really deal with eigenvalues at all, as the smallest singular value is the distance from a matrix to the nearest singular matrix

Comment: Thank you. Just a basic question but since I am only discussing positive semidefinite matrices, this distinction doesn't matter for my case, correct?

Comment: Yes, in the general case, you would need to discuss singular values. But in the case of positive semidefinite matrices, the singular values are given by the absolute values of the matrix's eigenvalues.